# How do I create an array of incrementally higher dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I'm trying to generate an array of times by adding 30 min repeatedly.
When I do this:

```
let t = new Date();
    t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    t.setHours(7);
    t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 30);
```

I get a time representing 7:30AM.
However when I do this:

```
let t = new Date();
    t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    t.setHours(7);
    let x = [];
    while (t.getHours() <= 22) {
      t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 30);
      x.push(t);
    }
    return x;
```

I get 30 or so items that are all 11:00PM.
I'm guessing its because they are all referring to the same object instead of copying the object. Using for loop does the same thing.

How would I go about getting my desired result of an array of different times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are pushing the same instance of a "Date" object, `t` onto your array on each iteration of the loop.  Each time you modify `t`, you are effectively modifying all the instances in your array.

You want to push a new instance of `Date` on each iteration of the loop.  The Date class in Javascript appears to happily accept another Date instance as a constructor param, so the fix is quite easy:

Simply change this line:

```
x.push(t);
```

To this:

```
x.push(new Date(t));
```

Full solution:

```
let t = new Date();
t.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
t.setHours(7);
let x = [];
while (t.getHours() <= 22) {
  t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 30);
  x.push(new Date(t));
}
return x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.from({length: 500}, (_, i) => new Date(Date.now() + i*1000*60*30))
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

It's beacause you are pushing the same t in your array, each time. Instead of

> `t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 30);`

use

> let addedTimeInMilliSeonds = t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 30);
>
> x.push(new Date(addedTimeInMilliSeonds ));`

and you should be fine. (If you do not need t's previous values anymore)